# Base module in odoo 9 is not in addons folder

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

I am trying to find base module in odoo 9 to check out original code for base models such as 'res.partner' and 'res.users' but didn't find it
Anyone know how to find it? I need the path

Comment: have you find in modules folder ?

Comment: Yes, Addons folder

Comment: No, i am talking about the folder named as "module" ?

Comment: No folder should be named "module", I am asking about module named "base" which has models like 'res.partner'

Comment: have you update your module list from browser ?

Comment: @AhmerSaeed the "Base" module is a system module in odoo not module I create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it finally,

openerp/addons/base/res

Answer (score 0):

you can found it  under /opt/odoo/openerp/addons/base

(*) /opt/odoo/ is the odoo installation directory in my case.